# Matlab's Import Tool recognizes a column as numbers but generate %s in formatSpec

Tags: matlab, csv, import

I use Matlab's [Import Tool](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/import-data-interactively.html) to generate a script that will take care of importing several CSV files with the same columns.

The Import Tool successfully manages to recognize the type of each column of my CSV file:

[image]

However, in the generated script, the same column are cast as strings (`%s` = string):

[image]

Any idea why?

Surprisingly it works fine with CSV files with fewer columns (it works with 70-column CSV files, but the issue arises with with 120-column CSV files). [Here is one example of a CSV file that triggers the issue](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q5310pnkonb1lyp/ecg_ahe_windows_2_lead_3000_lag_600?dl=0).

I use R2014b x64 with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because one of the columns in your file contains data which contains numbers and text.  The Import Tool is predicting that you're going to want to extract the numbers from this field, so it labels the column as 'NUMBER'.  However, standard textscan doesn't allow for this, so the Import Tool must generate code to read in all of the data as text, and does the numeric conversion afterwards.  The Import Tool is trying to help avoid errors using textscan.

The result of running the generated code is still numeric, as is shown in the Import Tool.

The specific column is labeled SEGMENT_ID in your example file. It contains data like:

l8K3ziItQ2pRFQ8
L79Y0zA8xF7fVTA
JYYqCCwRrigaUmD